# Upload file with Dropbox SDK for iOS get Error Code 403

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

i'm trying to upload a file using the dropbox SDK for ios, i have setup correctly the framework, and link with the dropbox account, but now when i'm trying to upload the file i receive this error:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/sandbox/DBApp.sqlite - (403) Forbidden
2013-08-28 15:07:12.418 MyApp[3761:c07] File upload failed with error - Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)" UserInfo=0x11e77ef0 {sourcePath=/Users/Piero/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/553ACC67-D119-44A9-B7E0-7188773AD496/Documents/DBApp.sqlite, destinationPath=/sandbox/DBApp.sqlite, error=Forbidden}
```

this is the code i use:

```
NSString *filename = @"DBApp.sqlite";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
NSString *oldPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBApp.sqlite"];
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:oldPath];
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the problem, i have wrong to create the type account of the app in the dropbox page, i have choose Datastore Only, instead i have to choose file and Datastore, i have delete the account, and create a new one, and know with the code above works!

Answer (score 1):

Just for detail description, I was also getting the same error and followed a sample project from the Ray Wenderlich tutorial sites.

Steps I have taken are as follows:

1. register(create) your app on drop box developer.
2. Choose DropBox API App
3. Choose sub type i.e What type of data does your app need to store on Dropbox: Files and Data-stores
4. Choose appropriate option Can your app be limited to its own folder?
5. What type of files does your app need access to? ----> choose specific file type

For a full understanding have a look at attached snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ya I support Piero answer and another reason is that the access token is invalid so I suggest you to add the DBRestClient instance in your appdelegate OpenURL function so, your appdelegate class will have some thing like this
**AppDelegate .m**
[image]

and in your **ViewController** add the DBRestClient instance from **AppDelegate** class in ViewDidLoad Method and your ViewController will looks something  like this
[image]

This solves the issue and working fine