# DropBox ios SDK error: (403) Parameter not found: oauth_token

Tags: ios, xcode

I use DropBox iOS SDK to synchronise update files of my application and load Metadata. I have an Error when i execute the project that is:

> Error loading metadata: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)"
>   UserInfo=0x8a845d0 {path=/, error=Parameter not found: oauth_token}
>   error making request to /1/metadata/sandbox - (403) Parameter not
>   found: oauth_token

How can i install and enable oauth extension ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488937/upload-file-with-dropbox-sdk-for-ios-get-error-code-403

Comment: i choosed file and Datastore in the type account of the app